# Powershell script does not delete old files

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a script that, among the tasks, deletes log files with more than 10 days. But the files are not being deleted. Follow the code snippet

```
$LOCAL_BKP = 'E:\prod'
$QTD_DIAS = "-10"
$BACKUP_DATE = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S"
$ARQUIVO_LOG = "$($LOCAL_BKP)\log_backup_$($BACKUP_DATE).log"

Get-ChildItem –Path $LOCAL_BKP -Include *.log | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime –lt (Get-Date).AddDays($QTD_DIAS)} | Remove-Item -Recurse | Out-File -Append -NoClobber -filepath $ARQUIVO_LOG
```

Comment: Run the code first up to this part of the pipeline: `Get-ChildItem –Path $LOCAL_BKP -Include *.log | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime –lt (Get-Date).AddDays($QTD_DIAS)} ` because we need to know if any objects are found that match the filter for `Where-Object`.  If you run that command and nothing is retunred to screen, then nothing would be removed.

Comment: You are correct, nothing is being returned on the screen. If files exist in this folder, because I wouldn't be being returned?

Comment: Ah, try this instead `Get-ChildItem –Path $LOCAL_BKP\*.log | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime –lt (Get-Date).AddDays($QTD_DIAS)}` .  I find that `-Include` doesn't work the way most people think it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into this issue because of the way the `-Include` parameter works for `Get-ChildItem`.  From the help:

```
-Include <String[]>
    Gets only the specified items. The value of this parameter qualifies the Path parameter. Enter a path element or pattern, such as
    "*.txt". Wildcards are permitted.

    **The Include parameter is effective only when the command includes the Recurse parameter or the path leads to the contents of a
    directory, such as C:\Windows\*, where the wildcard character specifies the contents of the C:\Windows directory.**
```

Note the second part.  `-Include` only functions if you specify `-Recurse` or specify * for the path of a directory.

If you change your commandline to this:

```
Get-ChildItem –Path $LOCAL_BKP\*.log | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime –lt (Get-Date).AddDays($QTD_DIAS)}
```

It should work as expected.  If it still doesn't, make sure that you do have files older than 10 days present.